# Facebook Shared Album

Tags: facebook

I created on a shared album. It is possible that one day in the future, I may delete my account. If I, as the owner of a shared album on Facebook deactivate my account, does that delete the shared album?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that deletes the shared album as well since it's associated with your account.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if the owner you have shared album got deactivate then the album would be removed.The thing is if an user is sharing  the album then the album wont be sync & downloaded  to other account but the link is added to the other account so once it is deactivated,album would be disappeared.